# How do I install ccmake?

Tags: apt, software-installation

How do I install `ccmake` (not `cmake`)?

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
sudo apt-get install ccmake
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Install the package `cmake-curses-gui`. You can install it by clicking the below image:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or by executing the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake-curses-gui
```

Comment: That is the same as installing ccmake?

Comment: The package `cmake-curses-gui` contains the program `ccmake`

Answer (score 4):

```
$ apt-cache search ccmake
cmake-curses-gui - curses based user interface for CMake (ccmake)
xutils-dev - X Window System utility programs for development
```

(This is on Debian but Ubuntu usually has the same packages; you might possibly have to turn on the universe repository.)

In general, use `apt-cache search` to find specific package names.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
sudo apt-get install cmake-curses-gui
```

Hope that helps!